# Unexpected Initializing outcome from 2D array

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization

To initialize a 2D array, usually we can do it like this:

```
int matrix[3][4] = { {1,1,1,1}, {2,2,2,2}, {3,3,3,3} };
```

However, as I was testing it with various combinations, the following codes did compile out of my expectation:

```
int matrix[3][4] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
```

When I print out the output in a 2D-table form, I get:

```
1,2,3,4,
5,6,7,0,
0,0,0,0,
```

I understand why the rest of the values are zeroes.

**My question is**: Is this one of the legitimate ways to initialize 2D array by assuming the numbers which exceed the bounds of a row will always "flow" to the next row? Or is this another pitfall I should avoid in C++ ?

Comment: That's completely legitimate. It's been part of C and C++ since before standardisation. Although you might think the more explicit version is easier to read.

Comment: @AlanStokes Thanks for your reply, I was kind of surprise knowing that it is legitimate though, because I thought it does compile because C++ do not check the bounds, and the number just sit on the next available memory. Or can I say that, since the next available memory is also "reserved" as part of the array. It is fine to do so?

Comment: @user3437460 How can the compiler set any of the values to 0 if it doesn't check the bounds? If you exceed the bounds, it'll result in a compiler-error.

Comment: It's not easy to summarize all of the initialization rules, so I'll just leave [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization) here.

Comment: @user6276096 Hmm, yes you are right. It does check the number of initializers at compilation time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is perfectly fine. Quoting [the unofficial cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization):

> The braces around the nested initializer lists may be elided
>   (omitted), in which case as many initializer clauses as necessary are
>   used to initialize every member or element of the corresponding
>   subaggregate, and the subsequent initializer clauses are used to
>   initialize the following members of the object.

And:

> If the number of initializer clauses is less than the number of
>   members or initializer list is completely empty, the remaining members
>   are initialized  by empty lists, which performs value-initialization.

And value initializing an `int` sets it to `0`.